# why KeyError: 0 in flask application 127.0.0.1 - - [31/Oct/2019 00:01:07] "POST /results HTTP/1.1" 500 -?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, flask

i am making a flask application in which i had taken input from user through .html page and later i converted the values of different variables to a dictionary , which then converted into data-frame of pandas and stored inside a variable whose value at 0 index i want to display , but it is giving an error , how to solve it?

i am unable to recognize error and its cause.

the code used to predict value and show it includes:

```
dic = {'MRP':MRP,'Fat':Fat,'Visibility':Visibility,'Weight':Weight,'Years':Years}

fdata_input = pd.DataFrame(dic,index=[0],columns=['MRP','Fat','Visibility','Weight','Years'])                           

price = rf.predict(fdata_input[0])
```

//i want to display the value stored in fdata_input ' s index 0

this is error message that i am getting:

Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

127.0.0.1 - - [31/Oct/2019 00:00:58] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -

[2019-10-31 00:01:07,482] ERROR in app: Exception on /results [POST]

> `Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", 
>   line 2657, in get_loc
>       return self._engine.get_loc(key)
>     File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 108, in 
>   pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
>     File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 132, in 
>   pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
>     File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1601, in 
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
>     File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1608, in 
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
>   KeyError: 0
>   During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2292, in 
>   wsgi_app
>       response = self.full_dispatch_request()
>     File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1815, in 
>   full_dispatch_request
>       rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
>     File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1718, in 
>   handle_user_exception
>       reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
>     File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in 
>   reraise
>       raise value
>     File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1813, in 
>   full_dispatch_request
>       rv = self.dispatch_request()
>     File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1799, in 
>   dispatch_request
>       return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
>     File "<ipython-input-4-303728ed6a31>", line 51, in results
>       predicted_stock_price = rf.predict(fdata_input[0])
>     File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 
>   2927, in __getitem__
>       indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
>     File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", 
>   line 2659, in get_loc
>       return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
>     File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 108, in 
>   pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
>     File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 132, in 
>   pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
>     File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1601, in 
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
>     File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1608, in 
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
>   KeyError: 0`

127.0.0.1 - - [31/Oct/2019 00:01:07] "POST /results HTTP/1.1" 500 -

i want value at index 0 to be displayed of fdata_input.

Comment: Let us say your dic = {'MRP':'1','Fat':'2','Visibility':'3','Weight':'4','Years':'5'}. Now if you display fdata_input, it is something like   MRP Fat Visibility Weight Years
0   1   2          3      4     5. What do you exactly meab by printing fdata_input[0]...?? Which value do you want to print.?

Comment: i want all these values passed to variables help to predict a dependent variable say sales of an item , so what i thought is to  make a data frame out of these values , pass it to fdata_input and then pass it to model ( rf in code)  saved and loaded previously  and get sales of item using predict method.

Comment: then i want these predicted sales to be displayed using my flask application on localhost:5000/results

Comment: when i don't write fdata_input[0] and pass it to predict method as predicted=rf.predict(fdata_input)  ,  and then using render_template  i wrote   return render_template('resultsform.html', pred_sales=predicted)  ,  where pred_sales is my placeholder variable in result.html file where i want to show this value of sales , i know " predicted" variable gives a single value but when i pass it as so it says

Comment: ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32').
127.0.0.1 - - [31/Oct/2019 13:30:29] "POST /results HTTP/1.1" 500 -
127.0.0.1 - - [31/Oct/2019 13:30:30] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -